# Cross reference an embedded Excel file cell to a form field in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I have a Word 2007 document that is using the legacy form-fill tools in a table. Within this table, I have embedded an Excel table.  The Word file is protected, except for the signature blocks and the Excel table, which are separated out by section breaks.  All this seems to work fine.

I would like to link a cell from the Excel table to a form field in the Word table.  Is this possible?